# Resolving MIME checking for .svelte file when uploading to Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, svelte, mime-types

I have been working on a static webpage offline, and it works when I deploy it locally. I have now been trying to upload it to Firebase hosting, and have configured CLI etc. and can run the hosting. At a point, it calls a .svelte file, and this is not loading and I get the following error in the browser console:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

The error seems to indicate that it is in line 1 of the file "App.svelte". It calls a few other .svelte files, but I haven't got it to load past the first instance so do not know if this error would persist for all of them.

The start of the file is as follows:

```
<script>
  import CardList from "./cards.svelte";
  import Card from "./lib/components/card.svelte";
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

...

  onMount(() => {
    const $headings = document.querySelectorAll("h1,h2,h3");
    const $anchor = [...$headings].filter((el) => {
      const id = el.getAttribute("id")?.replace(/^.*?-/g, "");
      const hash = window.location.hash?.replace(/^.*?-/g, "");
      return id === hash;
    })[0];
    if ($anchor) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        $anchor.scrollIntoView();
      }, 100);
    }
  });
</script>
```

I have found limited information on defining the MIME type, but not how to do so in a .svelte file, and what I tried (adding `context = "module"`) did not work.

I'm really very stumped, and would appreciate any help.

When I run `npm run preview` to a local server, I get something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aidoa.png)

Whereas when I deploy it, the grey background, title, and icon load, but no content, with the following console error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3tJg.png)

Comment: How did you build and deploy your site.

Comment: I built it using VS Code, based on an existing template from another user. I deployed it using Firebase "firebase deploy --only hosting"

Comment: You're using `adapter-static`? https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static What's set as `public` directory in `firebase.json`?

Answer (score 0):

When built, there are no svelte files left. These should all been compiled to javascript by the Svelte compiler in the build step.

This import error can occur when you're deploying the source instead of the build output.